# Print all elements in linklist

Tags: c++, pointers

A question from C++ beginner...Since I would like to print all the element in my linklist, but the code I have only print the  first element. Any ideas?? Thank you !! Here is my code (any help is appreciated):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Entry{
string name,phone;
Entry *next;
};

void PrintEntry(Entry *e)
{
    cout<< e->name << " " << e->phone <<endl;
}

Entry *GetNewEntry()
{
    string name;
    cout<< "Enter name (ENTER to quit): ";
    getline(cin,name);
    if(name == "") return NULL;
    Entry *newOne = new Entry;
    newOne->name = name;
    cout<< "Enter phone: ";
    getline(cin, newOne->phone);
    newOne->next= NULL;
    return newOne;
}

Entry * Buildlist()
{
    Entry *list=NULL;
    while(true){
    Entry *newOne=GetNewEntry();
    if (newOne == NULL) break;
    newOne->next = list;
    list = newOne;
    }
    return list;
}

int main()
{
    Entry *n=Buildlist();
    PrintEntry(n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, your code explicitly prints one element. So, print more of them.

Comment: @juanchopanza Could you please explain a little bit? could you please rewrite the print par of my code, if possible...Thanks

Comment: No, it is your linked list. Follow the links, printing each element.

Comment: http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/103/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void PrintAll(Entry *e)
{
  for(;e;e = e->next)
      PrintEntry(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code. Here are some hints...
Within your BuildList() function when you make the assignment:
    list = newOne;
You are only saving the "last" entry to the list. All of the previous entries are orphaned.

The statement:
 newOne->next = list;
Really does nothing... it simple NULL terminates newOne->next (since 'list' is still NULL). This field is already set to NULL from the previous GetNewEntry() call.

The fundamental problem with your code is that you are not actually linking each of the new created nodes to each other and only retaining the last node with list. Once you get that fixed, your PrintEntry() needs to be called within a loop that traverses your list to print each element.